# Login form IF-ELSE not working well

Tags: java, swing, authentication, text-files

**Note** Data inside text file as below:

- customer-1-Customer
- coach-1-Sport Coach
- coach2-1234-Sport Coach
- customer2-1234-Customer

**PROBLEM**
*1.* Program can read data 1&2. But once it goes into the particular Menu, it also execute the else statement which will shows the pops up window.
*2.* Data 3&4 couldn't be read, it straight goes to else statement although Username & Password been entered correctly.

```
private void btn_ConfirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    Admin = txt_Username.getText();
    Admin_Pass = txt_Password.getText();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(("USER_Account.txt")));

        String s;
        String TOU;
        String UIusername; //txt_Username.getText();
        String UIpassword; //txt_Password.getText();
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    {   
       String tmp [] = s.split("-");

       UIusername = tmp[0];
       UIpassword = tmp[1];
       TOU = tmp[2];

        if (txt_Username.getText().equals(UIusername) && txt_Password.getText().equals(UIpassword) && TOU.equals("Sport Coach"))
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Logged in as Coach!","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            SportCoach_Menu spMenu = new SportCoach_Menu();
            this.hide();
            spMenu.show();
        }
        else if (txt_Username.getText().equals(UIusername) && txt_Password.getText().equals(UIpassword) && TOU.equals("Customer"))
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Logged in as Customer!","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Customer_Menu cMenu = new Customer_Menu();
            this.hide();
            cMenu.show();
        }
        else if (Admin.equals("admin") && Admin_Pass.equals("1234"))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Logged in as Admin!","",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Staff_Menu sMenu = new Staff_Menu();
            this.hide();
            sMenu.show();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Username / Password, please retry!","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            txt_Username.setText(null);
            txt_Password.setText(null);
        }        
    }
    br.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Much thanks for helping out!!

Comment: Your variable names... Partially horrible. What is TOU meant to mean?

Comment: Your mixing uses of Admin and Admin_Pass with txt_Username.getText() and txt_Password.getText()... this probably isn't your problem but it's bad form

Comment: @GhostCat sorry, it was meant to be (Type of User)

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert so is there any way I can convert it into a better form of code? Cause for "admin" it has to be pre-defined only

Comment: You'll probably want to check to "admin" first, before do anything else

Comment: You can convert it using a text editor or an IDE (by hand or with a "refactor" wizard), but you will need to tell the tool what variable names to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I made a few modifications. Ask if you don't understand anything.

Instead of reading the textfields I hardcoded the values. You should change this back.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Admin = "coach2";
        String Admin_Pass = "1234";

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(("USER_Account.txt")));

            String s;
            String TOU;
            String UIusername; //txt_Username.getText();
            String UIpassword; //txt_Password.getText();
            boolean loggedIn = false;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null && !loggedIn) {
                String tmp[] = s.split("-");

                UIusername = tmp[0];
                UIpassword = tmp[1];
                TOU = tmp[2];

                if (Admin.equals(UIusername) && Admin_Pass.equals(UIpassword) && TOU.equals("Sport Coach")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as Coach!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    loggedIn = true;
                } else if (Admin.equals(UIusername) && Admin_Pass.equals(UIpassword) && TOU.equals("Customer")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as Customer!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    loggedIn = true;
                } else if (Admin.equals("admin") && Admin_Pass.equals("1234")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in as Admin!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    loggedIn = true;
                }
            }
            if (!loggedIn)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username / Password, please retry!", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```